# Karate-afterFeature - main feature file cannot call another feature file using Karate-afterFeature

Tags: graphql, karate

I have a problem with Karate `afterFeature` configuration.

I want to call a clean up step from a separate feature file after every scenario. Hence, I configured a `afterFeature` js function, that should call that cleanup feature using karates `call` function.

The `callonce` works fine in prior step, but I have problem with the `afterFeature`.

This is the code how I configure `afterFeature`:

```
    * def result = callonce read('../callOnceCreateCompanyForBrowse.feature')
    * def id = result.response.data.createCompanyEvent.id
    * configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('../../deleteCompanyEvent.feature', {id : id}); }
```

Comment: no one can help you with the lack of information, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: The way you configured and used `afterFeature` should work. 
@PeterThomas is right when he says, that it's very likely that you didn't get the path to your feature file right.

Comment: @PeterThomas - My bad. I should have attached the entire file but this is my first time posting a question. Anyways, I have considered your suggestion of using classpath as well. I was running the feature file directly without using the runner class. That is why the afterFeature file isn't being called. I tried running it from a runner and it worked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion, instead of relative paths (which is hard to get right) use the `classpath:` prefix.

```
* configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('classpath:com/myco/deleteCompanyEvent.feature', { id: id }) }
```

EDIT: looks like the solution was using a runner instead of running the feature directly.